# Recommended Twig file extension

Tags: php, html, templates, twig

Is there a recommended file extension for Twig templates?  I've seen the following used, and would like to be consistent with the majority of other developers.

- myTemplate.html.twig
- myTemplate.twig
- myTemplate.html
- myTemplate.tmpl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you define the format before the `.twig` extension. So when you work with Symfony2 for example you can define the output format.

`myTemplate.json.twig` for example. So normally you should use that format. But you don't need that.

Here is an issue but you can see how it works

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2920

Comment: Thanks Stony, Yea, I know it doesn't really matter, but just want to start off similar to others.  I don't use Symfony2, but agree I should follow there lead.