# Twig Render File Type

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

I need to load both file types (HTML / PHP) as there are multiple files in HTML and PHP.

```
    /**
     * Render the provided view.
     *
     * @param string $view The view to render.
     * @param array $args  Array of arguments to pass to the view.
     */
    public function render($view, $args = []) {
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->args = $args;

        echo $this->twig->render("{$this->view}.html", $this->args);
    }
```

I need it to be able to load both HTML and PHP files, I just cannot seem to figure this out.

Thanks, Jake.

Comment: You do realise that the php inside the files won't be rendered right?

Answer (score 1):

A raw call to `file_exists`, as proposed by ceejayoz, will not work if you use templates in namespaced twig paths. Then this will do better, as it resolves the paths through the file loader first:

```
$view = '';
$loader = $this->twig->getLoader();
if($loader->exists('{$this->view}.html')) {
  $view = '{$this->view}.html';
} else if($loader->exists('{$this->view}.php')) {
  $view = '{$this->view}.php';
} else {
  throw new \RuntimeException('View not found');
}
echo $this->twig->render($view, $args);
```

Comment: Lovely, a big +1 from me. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @ceejayoz you're welcome - but I must admit that your answer triggered me to write another answer, as I had to deal with a similar case some months ago

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if(file_exists("{$this->view}.html")) {
    echo $this->twig->render("{$this->view}.html", $this->args);
} elseif(file_exists("{$this->view}.php")) {
    echo $this->twig->render("{$this->view}.php", $this->args);
} else {
    throw new Exception('uh oh');
}
```

That said, you might consider [standardizing on the `.twig` extension for templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960065/recommended-twig-file-extension).